# Product list with ID on backend

Tags: product, product-list, backend

Hi i have this form on backend with select input.

```
 $fieldset->addField('product_id', 'select', array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('banermanager')->__('Product ID'),
                        'values'   => Iv_BanerManager_Block_Adminhtml_Banermanager_Grid::getValueArray3(),
                        'name' => 'product_id',
                        ));
```

What do i have to change on 'values' to get list of all products on shop with their id's ?

Comment: I think the easiest would be to implement your own source model for `values`, instantiate this and call getAllOptions(). Just search for this method inside of magento to get an idea how to implement it and what you need to return

Answer (score 1):

You can make your field config look like this:

```
//I'm not sure which one is correct, but I has 2 be one of the 2 - try them both
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->toOptionArray();
//or
//$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->toOptionHash();


$fieldset->addField('product_id', 'select', array(
       'label'     => Mage::helper('banermanager')->__('Product ID'),
       'values'   => $products,
       'name' => 'product_id',
));
```